# KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with JBoss stadalon.xml

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I have recently started using keycloak for authentication and authorization of our application.
I have used KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as explained in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter for the configuration. The KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is by default using the Keycloak.json, but we are using JBoss application server in our project and the keycloak server configuration is inside the standalone.xml subystem. Does KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter automatically detects it? Could someone help me please  to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter automatically detects it?

I dont think so. Your keycloak server has "multiple keycloak.json" (one keycloak json per client/application). Which one you choose?

You can implement org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver for load keycloak.json from custom path.

PS: keep it simple: store keycloak.json in your application

Comment: The problem is that the application is already configured with JBoss EAP/WildFly Adapter. And keycloak.json is replaced with  the JBoss subsytem in standalone.xml.  90% of our application runs in Java EE and configuration fits it. But unfortunately my part uses the KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.